# Install new wall outlet few feet to the left of existing outlet

Tags: electrical, receptacle

If  I wanted to install a wall outlet 3 feet to the left of a current outlet, would I have to take down the whole wall? It is possible and how much would it generally cost range?

The wall is already there existing home, it is on the same side of the wall as current outlet, I am in apartment condo in California.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We can't speak to the cost, but it's likely you can add the new outlet without a lot of trouble. We'll need more details to tell, though (e.g. wall construction? same side of wall as current outlet? your location?).

Comment: the wall is already there existing home, it is on the same side of the wall as current outlet, I am in apartment condo in California

Comment: Is the outlet installed into one of the party walls, or into a partition?

Comment: existing outlet is in the same partition of new location I want to build

Comment: What is on the other side of this wall?  A) a room in your own unit B) a room belonging to another tenant C) outdoors

Answer (score 1):

You can carefully remove the cove at the bottom of the wall. Then cut the drywall out from the area behind the base cove. You will need to notch the plate back so you can fish the NM behind the dry wall. Run the NM to the new location and repeat the notching up toward the new hole you just cut to install the cut-in box. Connect up the new receptacle put on the cover plate, then make up the connection at the old receptacle location (make sure the circuit is turned off). Replace the base turn on the power and you're good to go.

Stay safe and good luck.